# Airflow does not backfill latest run

Tags: airflow

For some reason, Airflow doesn't seem to trigger the latest run for a dag with a weekly schedule interval.

Current Date:

```
$ date
$ Tue Aug  9 17:09:55 UTC 2016
```

DAG:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='superdag',
    start_date=datetime(2016, 7, 18),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=7),
    default_args={
        'owner': 'Jon Doe',
        'depends_on_past': False
    }
)

BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag
)
```

Run scheduler

```
$ airflow scheduler -d superdag
```

You'd expect a total of four DAG Runs as the scheduler should backfill for 7/18, 7/25, 8/1, and 8/8. 
However, the last run is not scheduled.

[image: Airflow DAG Runs]

[image]

EDIT 1:

I understand that Vineet although that doesn’t seem to explain my issue.

In my example above, the DAG’s start date is July 18.

- First DAG Run: July 18
- Second DAG Run: July 25
- Third DAG Run: Aug 1
- Fourth DAG Run: Aug 8  (not run)

Where each DAG Run processes data from the previous week.

Today being Aug 9, I would expect the Fourth DAG Run to have executed with a execution date of Aug 8 which processes data for the last week (Aug 1 until Aug 8) but it doesn’t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Airflow always schedules for the previous period. So if you have a dag that is scheduled to run daily, on Aug 9th, it will schedule a run with execution_date Aug 8th. Similarly if the schedule interval is weekly, then on Aug 9th, it will schedule for 1 week back i.e. Aug 2nd, though this gets run on Aug 9th itself. This is just airflow bookkeeping. You can find this in the airflow wiki (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls):

> Understanding the execution date
>   Airflow was developed as a solution for ETL needs. In the ETL world, you typically summarize data. So, if I want to summarize data for 2016-02-19, I would do it at 2016-02-20 midnight GMT, which would be right after all data for 2016-02-19 becomes available.
>   This date is available to you in both Jinja and a Python callable's context in many forms as documented here. As a note ds refers to date_string, not date start as may be confusing to some.

Answer (score 2):

The similar issue happened to me as well. 
I solved it by manually run
`airflow backfill -s start_date -e end_date DAG_NAME`
where start_date and end_date covers the missing execution_date, in your case, 2016-08-08.
For example,
`airflow backfill -s 2016-08-07 -e 2016-08-09 DAG_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered a similar problem these days while learning apache airflow.

I think as Vineet has explained, given the way airfow works, you should probably use the execution date as **the beginning of DAG execution**, and not as **the end of DAG execution** as you said below.

> I understand that Vineet although that doesn’t seem to explain my issue.
>
> In my example above, the DAG’s start date is July 18.
>
> First DAG Run: July 18
> Second DAG Run: July 25
> Third DAG Run: Aug 1
> Fourth DAG Run: Aug 8 (not run)
>
> **Where each DAG Run processes data from
> the previous week.**

To make it work, you should probably use, for instance, July 18 as the **start date of the DAG execution for the week July 18 to July 22**, instead of **the end of the DAG execution for the week July 11 to July 15** for the week.