# Airflow backfill not completely filling up to the present

Tags: python-2.7, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm struggling with a weird problem I can't seem to figure out. I have a basic DAG that does nothing fancy. It just makes use of the bash operator to start a Python script.

I have this DAG scheduled to run every Monday. When I switch on the dag in the webserver it starts backfilling up to the 25th of September. However, it does not backfill for the 2nd of October. When I change the schedule from weekly to daily, it works fine.

This is my DAG setup.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'xxxxx',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['xxxxxx'],
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 9, 1, 0, 0),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
}


# Create DAG
dag = DAG(dag_id='IFS_weekly_forecast',
            schedule_interval = '0 8 * * MON',
          default_args=default_args)
```

As you can see from this picture, the backfilling is just fine up to the 25th. After that there are no new tasks queued.

[image: DAG runs]

What am I doing wrong here? I have other DAGs have been running fine for weeks. I also restarted the scheduler and the webserver, this did not help.

Edit:

The topic below seems to cover the same problem. However, this changes my question. How can I let airflow run weekly on a given date, instead of waiting for that entire period to finish?

[Airflow does not backfill latest run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856886/airflow-does-not-backfill-latest-run?rq=1)

Comment: Is there any dag_run instance for 10/02/2017?

Comment: As far as I can see there is no task instance or DAG instance in the webserver that relates to the 2nd of October 2017. I checked via 'Browse > Task Instances' and 'Browse > DAG Runs'.

Comment: Which version of airflow are you using? Have you tried to rename the dag_id and have a different start_date?